# Become friendly after being discovered as a werewolf

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Recently, I was playing The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim vanilla on xbox 360, and while I was playing, I turned into a werewolf in front of people in Riverwood and it caused them to become hostile.

I don't want to kill them. How can I make them friendly again without loading the last save? A lot of my precious items would disappear if I load the last save game.

Comment: If I remember correctly, all you get is a bounty for transforming into a werewolf. Try talking to the guards and see if you can pay off your bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming into a werewolf is a crime like any other; it has no lasting consequences and can be paid off in the same way: either by paying your bounty, or by serving jail time.

Comment: You need to leave the area though.  The bounty is high enough that you will not be able to yield to a hostile guard.  You can then pay the bounty somewhere else that isn't hostile to you on sight.